# IE8 scrolling is jerky and/or freezes the page

Tags: internet-explorer-8, scroll

Appears to be a well-documented issue with IE8 (http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/sites/thread?tid=7cbcfc2e558f909b&hl=en) but a client of mine is giving me a tough time over this. I'm on Mac but have tested on Windows XP/IE8 and can't even replicate the issue, nevermind fix it.

Also, I'm not really "fixing" anything since there's nothing wrong with the website – just IE8.

Anyway, has anyone come across similar issues before? Any help for me much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I’m having the same issue with IE8 on Windows XP.
Here was my code for an animate scroll with jQuery :

```
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: offset
});
```

The browser froze for what seemed the animation duration, so I changed my code for IE8 with :

```
$('html').scrollTop(offset);
```

But with the same freezing. I eventually disabled it entirely on IE8 (but if it was possible on my current work, it may not be an option in future ones…)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this works but Tools > Internet Options > Accessibility  - unchecking the box "reset text size to medium for new windows and tabs" totally fixed the problem for me in ie 11 running Windows 8.1 on a laptop.